# *.hbm.xml mapping files not loaded in test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

Please have a look at the project: https://github.com/darzz/boot_bug
This is the minimal setup, that reproduces the bug.

**Description**:
The application stack is Spring Boot with Spring Data and Spring Batch.
There is *testNamedQuery.hbm.xml* file under *src/main/resources/queries*.

When running from ***Application*** class the batch job finishes successfully, no exceptions in logs. However, when running from ***ApplicationNotWorking*** class, which is exact copy, just put in test source root, the batch job fails:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: findPersonNames
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getNamedQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.createQuery(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:146) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.getForwardOnlyCursor(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:123) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader.doOpen(HibernateCursorItemReader.java:185) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

**So it looks like** that when running tests, *.hbm.xml files are not loaded!
After research and debugging, I think, I might have found the cause - persistence unit root url is set for tests to target/test-classes, but the mapping files are in /target/classes.

**Possible cause** in my opinion may be similar to what's described in here http://blog.carbonfive.com/2007/05/17/using-classpath-vs-classpath-when-loading-spring-resources/

But I have no idea, how to solve this issue in Spring Boot, without creating persistence.xml configuration just for testing purposes. Don't want to copy *.hbm.xml files from main/resources to test/resources either.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load all the resources/beans during test, you should write test in different way than you have

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class DummyTest{

    @Test
    public void test(){
       //
  }
}
```

that should load all the resources with hbm mappings

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that is not the solution. I know this is the proper way to write tests, but the problem exists in either cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example.your.package")` on your Repository or your configuration class.